# Check if td is last visible td

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I want to check if the current grid cell is the last ***visible*** cell in the row.

```
//accurately confirms if cell is the last cell in the row, assuming there are no "display: none" cells after it
var isLastColumn = $(e.target).closest('td').is(':last-child');

//doesn't work - obviously because last-child gets the cell regardless of visiility
var isLastColumn = $(e.target).closest('td').is(':visible:last-child');

//doesn't work
var isLastColumn = $(e.target).closest('td').is('td.visible:last-of-type');

//doesn't work
var isLastColumn = $(e.target).closest('td').is(':visible:last');
```

How can I check to see if the selected cell is the last ***visible*** column of the row?

I am hooking to the event with the following:

```
    var grid = $("#@gridName").data("kendoGrid");
    grid.tbody.on('keydown', onGridKeydown)


    function onGridKeydown(e)
    {
        var isLastColumn = $(e.target).closest('td').is(':last-child');
    }
```

Comment: Please define your meaning of 'visible'. Do you mean that all the others are hidden in the DOM, or not visible because they're below the extents of the `window`?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I just mean a cell with no special modifiers or classes, i.e. the default visibility of a td. Invisible td's just have "display: none" set

Comment: The cells in question should be visible in the window and of course the DOM

Comment: In that case your second or fourth line should work, depending on what `e.target` is pointing at. Could you please show a working example of the problem.

Comment: @TruthOf42: Can you add the HTML markup you're working with, and the event wiring? What is `e.target`?

Comment: `I want to check if the current grid cell is the last visible cell in the row` Just check than any other following sibling isn't visible: `var isLastColumnVisible = !$(e.target).closest('td').nextAll(':visible').length;`

Comment: Assuming `e.target` inside the last visible `td` the last line `:visible:last` should work ► https://jsfiddle.net/1uhhew4d/ - there is a lot assumed here as we don't have the Html or event bindings.

Comment: @FrançoisWahl But `:last` works on global context, not relative to current row (`tr`). And anyway, it filters current matched element, it isn't relative to any other filtering condition, like e.g here `:visible`

Comment: @FrançoisWahl EDIT: looks like i'm wrong regarding `:visible:last` but still, `:last` isn't relative to row  https://jsfiddle.net/1uhhew4d/1/

Comment: @A.Wolff you are right `:last` is not in the context of each table or row. I assume if you give it the current row as context is should work.

Answer (score 2):

There is most likely a way more efficient way of doing it then below but it seems to work and can tell you if you are in the last visible column of the current row.

Taking into account you mentioned `display:none` was used to hide other columns you should be able to check if the current `td` in the current row is the last visible `td` elements.

```js
$('button').on('click', function(e) {
  var $td = $(e.target).closest('td');

  var isLastColumn = $td.is($td.closest('tr').find('td:visible:last'));
  alert(isLastColumn)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="table">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <button>
        1
      </button>
    </td>
    <td style="display:none">
      <button>
        2
      </button>
    </td>
    <td>
      <button>
        3
      </button>
    </td>
    <td style="display:none">
      <button>
        4
      </button>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <button>
        1
      </button>
    </td>
    <td style="display:none">
      <button>
        2
      </button>
    </td>
    <td>
      <button>
        3
      </button>
    </td>
    <td style="display:none">
      <button>
        4
      </button>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table id="table2">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <button>
        1
      </button>
    </td>
    <td style="display:none">
      <button>
        2
      </button>
    </td>
    <td>
      <button>
        3
      </button>
    </td>
    <td style="display:none">
      <button>
        4
      </button>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Here is a [**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/4dLye8L4/) as well

Comment: I was quite sure you couldn't use `:last` there but you just demonstrate that i was wrong.

Comment: @A.Wolff You were correct about `:last` not working in the original code, as well as my original example, because the context was not the current row but ones you set the context to the current row it should work

Comment: this works but so does "var isLastColumn = !$(e.target).closest('td').nextAll(':visible').length;", which is one line, but maybe harder to understand?